# JSON string overwriting?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I'm creating a view more comments script and I show a set amount of comments.. 2 at the moment but like facebook if there is more than that it says view all.. on my test post I have four comments in total, 2 showing and 2 hidden (In the database). I click this link and make a call for all comments, then will replace the existing 2 and also add show the other two.

So I have pretty much put everything together. But I've been told that I need to set a key of some description so the strings don't overwrite each other and I can't use the success 'response' 
So how would I go about doing this?

Returned data string via JSON array

```
{"comment_id":"1687","comment_poster":"33","comment_streamitem":"223","comment_datetime":"2014-08-23 17:24:10","comment_content":"ggg","username":"luce","id":"33","first":"lucy","middle":"","last":"ward"}{"comment_id":"1688","comment_poster":"33","comment_streamitem":"223","comment_datetime":"2014-08-23 17:24:13","comment_content":"hh","username":"luce","id":"33","first":"lucy","middle":"","last":"ward"}{"comment_id":"1689","comment_poster":"33","comment_streamitem":"223","comment_datetime":"2014-08-23 17:24:15","comment_content":"kkk","username":"luce","id":"33","first":"lucy","middle":"","last":"ward"}{"comment_id":"1690","comment_poster":"33","comment_streamitem":"223","comment_datetime":"2014-08-23 17:24:17","comment_content":"kk","username":"luce","id":"33","first":"lucy","middle":"","last":"ward"}
```

And the ajax call itself

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".view_comments").click(function() {
        var ID = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'viewmorecommentslink.php?comment_streamitem='+ ID,

            success: function(response){
                $("#comment_list_"+ID).append('<div class="stream_comment" id="comment_'+response['comment_id']+'" style="margin-top:0px;">\
                <table width=100%><tr><td valign=top width=30px><img class="stream_profileimage" style="border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;" border=\"0\" src=\"userimages/cropped'+response['comment_poster']+'.jpg\" onerror=this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ></a><td valign=top align=left>\
                <a href="/profile.php?username='+response['username']+'">'+response['first']+' '+ response['middle']+' '+response['last']+'</a> - <abbr class="timeago" title='+response['comment_datetime']+'>'+response['comment_datetime']+'</abbr>\<div class="commentholder">'+response['comment_content']+'</div><br/>\<div id="commentactivitycontainer">\
                <a style="cursor:pointer;" onClick=\"deletecomment('+response['comment_id']+',comment_'+response['comment_id']+');\">Delete</a><a id="likecontext_'+response['comment_id']+'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick=\"likestatuscomment('+response['comment_id']+',this.id);\">\
                <div style="width:80px; position:relative; float:left; left:40px" id="likescommentprint'+response['comment_id']+'">Like</div></a><div style="width:80px; position:relative; float:left; left:40px" id="likescommentprint'+response['comment_id']+'"></div>\
                </form><a id="dislikecontext_'+response['comment_id']+'" style="cursor:pointer;" onClick=\"dislikestatuscomment('+response['comment_id']+',this.id);\"><div style="width:90px; position:relative;top:-0px; float:left; left:200px" id="dislikescommentprint'+response['comment_id']+'">Dislike</div>\
                </a><div style="width:90px; position:relative; top:-0px; float:left; left:200px" id="dislikescommentprint'+response['comment_id']+'"></div></form></div></table></div></div>');

                $("#view"+ID).remove();
                $("#comment_list_"+ID).remove();
            }   
        });
        return false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is being overwritten please elaborate

Comment: The data strings are overwriting one another I presume @meda. How would ajax know what is a seperate comment through comment_id if the ajax calls for more than 1 result from the database. I can't use +response['comment_id']+ and so on.

Comment: you need to loop through the json, the id should not matter to ajax really

Comment: So I am getting all the data back in the response as you can see above. can you see any errors with the ajax as its not putting the 4 strings of data into its separate divs like I want it to. Yet it removes the 2 original comments.. I'm confused. all I get is one div appended with UNDEFINED on all the places the data should be.  @meda

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/4HxSr/71/

Comment: Ok that is all fine. I'm getting the data back its just not inputting into 4 divs..ahh this is frustrating.